# Существует ли максимум для массива (словаря, списка) при инициализации?

Tags: c#, словари

Например, если мне нужен dictionary в 300.000 строк, 
разумно ли его сразу запихать в код, 
или лучше читать из файла?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Количество элементов в Dictionary ограничивается  полем Capacity, а его значение в свою очередь - максимальным значением типа Int32. Значение это составляет 2 147 483 647. 
Однако на практике вы скорее всего не сможете создать Dictionary такого размера - получите OutOfMemoryException.

Теперь об инициализации. Нет, это неразумно. Конечно триста тысяч элементов скорее всего не вызовут OutOfMemory (ну если только у вас совсем мало памяти и/или размер каждого элемента слишком велик и при этом его передача происходит по значению (либо по ссылке, но ссылки нечасто повторяются)). Однако если вы запихнете инициализацию словаря на триста тысяч элементов в исходники, то скорее всего замучаетесь с навигацией по коду и, вполне вероятно, ваша IDE станет адски тормозить. Более того, сколько-нибудь адекватного обоснования для таких манипуляций просто нет, поэтому подобные неудобства по факту ничем не окупаются. 
Данные подобного размера имеет смысл либо хранить в базе/внешних файлах либо уж хотя бы генерировать в рантайме.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше читать, будет гибче.

Максимум существует - это когда вывалится OutOfMemoryException.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле инициализация словаря в коде скрытно вызывает то же самое добавление. Во всяком случае, в C# 3.0. Я тоже так делал, только для десятков тысяч элементов. Но даже для этого количества я все же передумал использовать такие костыли. Если уж сильно надо прямо в коде инициализировать - можно организовать partial class, чтобы отделить данные от кода. Вот как примерно у меня было:

```
partial static class BigData
{
    private static Dictionary<int, string> DICT =
    {
        { 1, "One" },
        { 2, "Two" }
    };
}

partial static class BigData
{
    public static string Get(int k)
    {
        string s;
        DICT.TryGetValue(k, out s);
        return s;
    }
}
```

Но, как я уже говорил, я отказался от этой идеи. Проще написать в конструкторе код на три строки, которые читают текстовый файл вида "1 One\n2Two", парсят его и заполняют словарь.